# Should I use Jquery- $.remove() when Re-Bind?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have html table which was generated from server side :

```
           DataTable dt2 = new Claims_Service().ASO_MOD_Get_Nulls();
           myGridView.DataSource = dt2;
           myGridView.DataBind();
```

The table has rows and in each row there is a button.

in client side I write :

```
 $(".myGridView").on('click', '.myButton', function ()
        {
          ...
        }
```

Now lets say I need to re-bind in server side. ( rebind ===  full postback and regenerate page)

Should I use jQuery `remove` function in order to release the *events and prevent memory leaks* before I rebind ?

Also , Would your answer will be different if I wrote :

```
$(".myGridView .myButton").on('click',function ()
```

Comment: Is the re-bind done via an AJAX method?  Is the class applied to an element that is being removed/re-added?

Comment: @tvanfosson no. Pure server command and regenerate html. I will write it in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to remove handlers when you are reloading the page via a full POST or GET request.  In any event, [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) will remove the elements from the DOM, not simply remove the event handlers.  To remove event handlers you want to use [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

Comment: @RoyiNamir - yes, it will also remove the handlers when it removes the elements from the DOM, but the primary function is to remove elements.  If you just want to remove handlers, use off().

Comment: the whole point is that I dont need NOTHING from the prev page. why dhouln't I use remove ?

Comment: If you are doing a full post, the browser itself should clean up the resources from the previous page.  You don't need to do it explicitly. I suppose that some browsers might leak memory, but I would expect that it's a function of their clean up code and probably would also leak if the handlers were removed manually too.

Comment: for clarity - so youre saying - I dont have to do nothing

Comment: Correct.  Reloading the page should take care of releasing the memory.

Comment: According to @kitgui - _jQuery calls .remove() when the page is onunload or abort._...ineteresting. I assume the browser will clean its handlers ( as you mentioned) - but apparently jquery will also do it before postback  - when the page unloads. **I should verify this info**

Answer (score 1):

If written like so:

```
$(".myGridView").on('click', '.myButton', function () { /* your code */ });
```

memory leaks are not a concern as you are pattern matching on dom bubble to all the ".myButton" occurances.

while

```
$(".myGridView .myButton").on('click',function () { /* your code */ });
```

is attaching to all the indivual ".myButton" occurrences

Comment: I think memory leeks CAN happend in the first scenario. The whole point is to shorten the bubble path. instead of bubble top the document element , it just bubble to the .MyGridView....

Comment: If you are destroying "myGridView" using ".remove()", jQuery cleans up after itself. Correct?

Comment: yeah. but the destruction is made by post back. the question is  : should I (before __dopostBack) need to clean something?

Comment: jQuery calls .remove() when the page is onunload or abort. The main point is to tax the browser memory less by attaching less events to dom. By using the first method, this is achieved.

Comment: _jQuery calls .remove() when the page is onunload or abort._ wow,,were is that written ?

Comment: Looking at the source is helpful for me. I'll double check but I remember seeing this before.

Comment: Well guess not. Its doing a lot with onunload and abort with ajax related. All I can contribute is telling you to attach at the higher level using a pattern rather than for individual to save on memory. I would check if memory leaks are an issue with jQuery though in the first place. The source is pretty readable: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js

Answer (score 0):

`on` applies a callback to any `.myButton` element, [no matter when it is added to the page](http://jqapi.com/#p=on) (it does the same job as the old `live` method). Using `remove` won't clean-up your client-side binding.

You should either [use `off`](http://jqapi.com/#p=off) or prevent the original binding (if the re-bind is done with a page postback).

Comment: _Using remove won't clean-up your client-side binding_ : Remopve will clean element+binding . why should I use it

Comment: As you're binding with 'on', every element 'now and in the future' will have the click event binded... that's why remove won't do a proper clean-up. Of course remove will remove the element, and thus the binding associated to these elements, but definitely it won't remove the binding to all .myButton elements.